# Umbraco DateTime Picker Custom Validation

Tags: validation, umbraco

Have noticed that umbraco datepicker property doesn't allow for dates before 1900. Is there someway I can customize the validation to allow for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minDate in the bootstrap date time picker is set to 1900. You can override this by setting the following variable (in this example I'm setting it to 1800):

```
$.fn.datetimepicker.defaults.minDate = moment({y: 1800});
```

You COULD change this in the source JS for Umbraco, but you'd lose the change if you updated Umbraco at any point. Your best bet is to add it as a script, and include it in your back offices pages using a package manifest in the app_plugins folder, something like this:

```
{
    "javascript" : [
        '~/App_Plugins/YourFolder/yourfile.js'
    ]
}
```

Where your file sets the variable.

There is some more information on this issue here: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/69475-date-picker-for-pre-1900-dates

Comment: Thank you! I did end up finding the answer by myself but I will give this the tick regardless :)